# TWRP: vendor partition is not existed

Tags: adb, twrp, lineageos, oneplus-5

I try to flash LineageOS on a OnePlus 5 (cheeseburger).  I installed TWRP 3.3.0-0 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cheeseburgerdumplings/files/16.0/cheeseburger/recovery/twrp-3.3.0-0-20190427-codeworkx-cheeseburger.img/download). I repeatedly wiped the partitions.

What I cannot manage is to `adb sideload` LineageOS [16.0](https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/full/cheeseburger/20190509/lineage-16.0-20190509-nightly-cheeseburger-signed.zip).  I get this message:

```
Starting ADB sideload feature...
Installing zip file '/sideload/package.zip'
Error: Vendor partition doesn't exist!
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
```

I have read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/9vu4lj/oneplus_5t_failure_to_install_los_151/) that I should install the latest stock ROM (from [here](https://www.oneplus.com/support/softwareupgrade/details?code=5)), but that results in almost the same error message:

```
Starting ADB sideload feature...
Installing zip file '/sideload/package.zip'
vendor partition is not existed, exit ota!!
Updater process ended with ERROR: 7
```

How can I create/populate/fix that vendor partition?

Answer (score 1):

OnePlus 5 didn't support project Treble out of the box, so there was no `/vendor` partition. However with update to Android P (as explained [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5t-project-treble-oxygenos-beta/)), said partition was created to support Treble. If you didn't undergo that OTA update, you must haven't `/vendor` partition on your device.

You can also create the partition yourself from within TWRP if you are a bit tech savvy. `parted` or `gdisk` can be used for the purpose. But playing with partition table could be risky if you aren't sure what you are doing. You can see the partition table of your device in given link.

Answer (score 1):

The `/vendor` partition was first introduced on OnePlus 5 with OxygenOS 5.1.4.  You will first need to flash that image on your phone so that the proper partitions are created.  [This post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/op5-rom-ota-oos-mirrors-for-official-oxygenos-roms-and-incremental-otas.3628190/) on xda-developers forums has download links to older firmware.

I would recommend reverting to stock recovery image (download link in the same post), then flashing OOS 5.1.4, and finally trying again with latest versions of TWRP and LineageOS.